# Javascript Bound function event data is null or not an object in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

This is working fine everywhere except for IE, when you click #doorbell IE says view.knock is null or not an object and fails out, I'm guessing it has something to do with the bind function in enableKnock and its not passing event data?

**Solved**: I changed the detectKnock function to:

```
detectKnock: function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.data.knockInput.push({
        time: (new Date()).getTime()
    });

    clearTimeout(e.data.completeId);
    e.data.completeId = setTimeout(e.data.completeKnock, 1200);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
},
```

the error happens here:

```
e.view.knock.knockInput.push({
     time: (new Date()).getTime()
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="doorbell">Push Me</button>
```

Javascript

```
var knock = Object();
knock = {
    successCallback: '',
    secretKnock: '',
    knockInput: [],
    reject: 0.25,
    averageReject: 0.15,
    fadeTime: 150,
    completeTime: 1200,
    completeId: '',
    lastNow: '',
    clickEventType: ((document.ontouchstart!==null) ? 'click':'touchstart'),

    enableKnock: function (callback, knock) {
        this.successCallback = callback;
        this.secretKnock = knock;
        $('#doorbell').bind(this.clickEventType, this, this.detectKnock);
    },
    disableKnock: function() {
        $('doorbell').unbind(this.clickEventType, this.knock.detectKnock);
        clearInterval(completeId);
    },
    detectKnock: function(e) {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        e.view.knock.knockInput.push({
            time: (new Date()).getTime()
        });

        clearTimeout(e.view.knock.completeId);
        e.view.knock.completeId = setTimeout(e.view.knock.completeKnock, 1200);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    },
    completeKnock: function() {
        if (this.knock.validateKnock()) {
            this.knock.successCallback();
        }
        this.knock.knockInput = [];
    },
    validateKnock: function() {
        var maxTime = 0;
        var times = [];
        var time;
        var result = true;
        var dist, i;
        var timeDiff, totalDiff;

        if (this.secretKnock.length == this.knockInput.length) {
            for (i = 1; i < this.knockInput.length && result; ++i) {
                time = this.knockInput[i].time - this.knockInput[i - 1].time;
                times.push(time);
                maxTime = Math.max(maxTime, time);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < times.length && result; ++i) {
                timeDiff = Math.abs((times[i] / maxTime) - this.secretKnock[i].delay);
                totalDiff += timeDiff;
                if (timeDiff > this.reject) {
                    result = false;
                }
            }

            if (result && totalDiff / times.length > this.averageReject) {
                result = false;
            }
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
};

    // Shave-and-a-haircut, two bits!
    var secret = [
        {delay:0.5},
        {delay:0.25},
        {delay:0.25},
        {delay:0.5},
        {delay:1},
        {delay:0.5},
        {delay:0}
    ];

    knock.enableKnock(allowInside, secret);

    function allowInside() {
        $('#sub_header').remove();
        $('#images').html('<div class="row" id="welcome"><div class="span12"><h1>Welcome to the afterparty.</h1></div></div>');
        $('body').fadeOut(7500);
        setTimeout( function() {  window.location='party.html' }, 1500 );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IE 8, event DTOs are only members of the window object, and not passed onto event listeners, hence any attempted invocation on `e` returns `null`:

```js
detectKnock: function(e) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    e.view.knock.knockInput.push({
        time: (new Date()).getTime()
    });

    clearTimeout(e.view.knock.completeId);
    e.view.knock.completeId = setTimeout(e.view.knock.completeKnock, 1200);
//---^----- error on null access 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

**From quirksmode.org:**

> In the Microsoft event accessing model there is a special property
>   window.event that contains the last event that took place.

[**Source**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html)

Comment: I had the same error in jsFiddle running in Chrome. `Cannot read property 'knockInput' of undefined`. This does not only seem to be the case in IE. When running: `console.log(e.view)` in Chrome it was `window` object.

Comment: interesting, could you provide a live demo reproducing that?

Comment: Try this one in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/JTUAh/ . When I click the button the console outputs: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'knockInput' of undefined` When I then add a `console.log(e.view);` as a first line inside the `detectKnock` method it outputs the window object `>window` before the error.

Comment: ooops, that's jQuery. forget about it, event is not a member of the `window`. please **un**-accept my answer so i can delete it. we wouldn't wanna be deceiving anyone.